# Simplicial polyhedral fans and shellability

Tags: polytopes, simplicial-complex

A simplicial polyhedral fan $\Sigma \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is a collection of simplicial polyhedral cones $\{\alpha_1 v_1 + \dots + \alpha_r v_r : \alpha_r \geq 0\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, where the $v_i$ are linearly independent, such that faces of cones are contained in $\Sigma$ and two cones intersect on faces. It is complete if the cones of $\Sigma$ span of all $\mathbb{R}^n$. Assume furthermore that each cone $\sigma$ is strongly convex, $\sigma \cap -{\sigma} = \{0 \}$.

This defines a simplicial complex $\Delta(\Sigma)$ which has a vertex for each dimension 1 cone and the vertices span a simplex if their corresponding cones span a higher-dimensional cone. A simplicial complex is shellable if there exists a well-order $\tau_1 \prec \dots \prec \tau_t$ on the maximal cones of $\Sigma$ such that the simplicial complex
$$\Delta(\tau_j \cap \bigcup_{i < j} \tau_i)$$
satisfies that every cone in it is contained in a maximal cone (of codimension 1 in $\Sigma$), which is also called pure. My question is whether this simplicial complex is always shellable? In my opinion its geometric realisation should be a polytope, which are shellable as is shown in [Ziegler's book "Lectures on Polytopes"](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4613-8431-1_8). His notion is of shellability is stronger than ours but should imply ours.

On the other hand the [article of Kleinschmidt and Onn](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02711519.pdf) states that this is an open problem to which the answer is likely negative. The examples of non-shellable simplicial complexes I could find, all use this stronger notion of shellability, for example [Rudin's ball](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1958-64-03/S0002-9904-1958-10168-8/S0002-9904-1958-10168-8.pdf), which does not imply non-shellability in our sense.